# Get existed db mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this code in my index.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect(secret);

const User = new mongoose.Schema({
    id: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
    money: { type: Number, default: 0 }
})
const user = mongoose.model('User', User);
```

And i have connected mongoose in different host. How do i get it in my different host?

Comment: In the same way

Comment: Just copy and paste?